# How can I avoid mixing two or more languages when I speak?

Tags: multiple-languages, speaking, communicative-strategies

When I speak L2 or L3, I say sometimes some words from the other languages that I know. I also have seen many people who have the same issue, they speak in English in some conference for example and then suddenly they say some words from French. What is the most effective way to avoid this or at least minimize its effect on our language speaking?

**Edit:**

Like I have already said, my question is more about this issue when we speak, and not with the whole language skills, and I agree that this happens a lot from the languages that we know better to the languages that we know less, but it might also happen in the other case, I mentioned this in the comments below though.

Comment: Great question. For some reason I catch myself thinking in another language while I am speaking in English. My wife simply tells me to think in English and I am okay.

Comment: Related: https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/319/how-can-i-deal-with-previously-learned-languages-vocabulary-confusing-me-when-i https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-there-any-studies-which-address-the-effectiveness-of-studying-multiple-relat Possible duplicate: https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-are-some-techniques-to-better-differentiate-between-the-two-languages

Comment: @Hatchet, I took a look at those questions before I posted this one but they are not exactly why I am looking for, my focus here is more on speaking not all the other skills.

Comment: @ettanany Does it happen with words that you know very well in both L2 and L3? Or are you mixing words from the language you know better into the language you know less?

Comment: @michau It might happen in both cases but usually from the language that we know better into the language that we know less.

Comment: Please, please, edit your question to explain what it is that you don't find in the questions that Hatchet listed in his comment. Otherwise, this question is at risk of getting closed.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Just edited my question, I hope that it is clear now. I have already mentioned that point in these comments, I said that mixing languages might happen in both cases.

Comment: @fi12 I do not consider this question as a duplicate of the other one. The other question is about learning strategies that should reduce confusion, whereas this question is about *language production*. In order to mark this question as a duplicate, you need to prove that only learning strategies can help solve this issue. Where is the evidence for that?

Comment: @Hatchet As I said in my previous comment, I don't consider this a duplicate until someone shows evidence to the contrary. Compare [language learning strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_learning_strategies), which is what the other question is about, with [communication strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_strategies_in_second-language_acquisition), which seems to be what this question asks about.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I see your point. It seems that https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/319/how-can-i-deal-with-previously-learned-languages-vocabulary-confusing-me-when-i may be a more accurate duplicate, however, especially because the top answer from this question and the top answer from that question both essentially say that practice is the solution.

Comment: @Hatchet That question is closer, but recommending practising is rather vague as an answer...

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Both answers say more than simply recommending practicing. This question, as I understand it, is asking How to avoid sometimes saying some words from the other languages I know? while the other is asking How to prevent languages you've learned in the past from interfering with a language you're learning now? which seem like basically the same question to me.

Comment: @Hatchet what about the second part of my question? I said that it might happen even with languages that we speak perfectly including our native language.

Comment: @ettanany One's native language was learned in the past.

Comment: @Hatchet But what is your answer to my question in this case? You mean I need to learn it again even if it is the language that I use everyday? because I did not find the answer for this question in this site!

Comment: @ettanany A native language need not be "learned again", especially if it is already well understood, but it should still be practiced. If you're looking for an answer more specific than "practice", I'd suggest reading the accepted answer for the question this question is marked as a duplicate of: http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/2063/85

Answer (score 5):

Practice, practice, practice.

I met some polyglots at the Polyglot Gathering in Berlin and a lot of them are simply very strict with themselves. One that I met usually has tandem meetings where he speaks in one language and his partner another. That is one way to get used to the interference of another language.

Look at the words that you "get wrong" and think about why you used those words instead of the ones you should have. Sometimes I feel that a concept is much better in one language than another and that means that I'll use it. One has to know one's audience and use one's Fingerspitzengefühl for that, of course.

It could be that you don't know the words as well as you should. Write then down, say the sentences over and over again and use those words until they roll off your tongue.

Good luck!

Comment: Interesting answer but what about when the speaker is extremely with both languages?

Answer (score 1):

1. *Restricting the use of each language to specific communicative situations: specific subjects and/or groups of people, etc.*
   A typical example is using English as the means of professional communication, even when having other (possibly native language) in common. Seems difficult at first, but it is in fact an easily acquired skill and practiced in many professional communities. In academic environment I have known whole research groups using, English as the means of communication, while, e.g., being physically located in France or Germany. Notably, this avoids misusing equivalent technical terms in other languages, that can be very misleading.
2. *Avoiding frequently switching between languages*
   The most marked case of mixing languages is in immigrant communities, where the native language is routinely used with admixture of terms that are frequently used in the country of residence and do not have clear equivalents in the native language (or have unwieldy equivalents). When returning to their native countries, such immigrants often find themselves unable to communicate in their native language without using foreign words. Similar things take place in multilingual families. The only way to avoid this is by exercising self-discipline and excluding such foreign borrowings (admittedly easier said than done).
3. *Refreshing/reviving the language*
   As an extreme example, one may be used to speak in everyday situations in a local language, and unable to use any other language when transposed to similar situations in the another country, despite knowing the local language much better (e.g., as the one's mother tongue) - to the extent of being mistaken for a foreigner. Spending a few weeks using the local language however helps to overcome this difficulties.

When dealing with second language, it may be sometimes helpful to have a short refresher course to *load the language in one's brain* (e.g., by reading through a *Colloquial X* book or something like that or simply doing some reading or watching movies in the target language.)

4. *Accepting this as inevitable in a weaker language*
   When you lack words/expressions in a language, you will be tempted to substitute from other languages, where the necessary word/expression easier comes to mind - that is those that you know better or use more frequently. This is particularly prone to happen when you find yourself under pressure - e.g., when you have to answer quickly or when you are engaged in a conversation and cannot stop in a middle of phrase. This is unavoidable.